# the breakpoint will not currently be hit no symbols loaded

Tags: .net, iis, debugging

I want to debug on the customer's machine (Windows Server 2003) to track a problem, and out product is based on .NET 2.0. I want to use DbgCLR.exe to debug a file **AAA.dll**, what I did is:

1. install .NET 2.0 SDK on the customer's machine (to get the DbgCLR.exe)
2. copy the symbol file AAA.pdb to the same directory with AAA.dll
3. get the source file for AAA.dll

the AAA.dll will be loaded by **w3wp.exe**, so in the DbgCLR

1. Tools->Attach to Process, then I choose **w3wp.exe**
2. File->Open->File  open the source file and add a breakpoint in the function which will be callled

but the breakpoint seems do no work because there is an warning icon on it and says : the breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

On my computer (Windows XP) which has the debug version of whole source code, I did nearly the same thing as above but the different is:
I attached **aspnet_wp.exe** to do the debug and it works

What should I do to let it work on the customer's machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to Debug / Windows / Modules. Find the AAA.dll, right click and select Load Symbols.

Also, you may need to disable JustMyCode in Tools / Options / Debugging.

Comment: Disabling JustMyCode is what fixed it to me. Thanks a lot.