# The breakpoint will not currently be hit, cshtml

Tags: c#, razor

In my Asp.Net Razor application i keep getting breakpoint will not currently be hit i have tried every single solution here [the breakpoint will not currently be hit no symbols loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013337/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-loaded) with no luck. So what should i do next?

Some Information:

1. I am using Debug mode.
2. I am using Nancy.Templates to create a NancyFx project.
3. The created project is set as Class Library.
4. When i locate the module while code is running, it is loaded from
   GAC for some reason.
5. I tried every possible thing, clean rebuild, creating new fresh
   project to test on, re-installing visual studio, even windows. Non
   works!
6. I am running on Windows 8.1, using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, .Net
   4.5.1

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">

    <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.NancyCSharpRazorBuildProvider, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders" />
        <add extension=".vbhtml" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.NancyVisualBasicRazorBuildProvider, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders" />
      </buildProviders></compilation>

    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
  <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*" />
    </httpHandlers></system.web>



<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Nancy" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer><appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings><system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor></configuration>
```

Here is the only .cshtml file i have in the solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> //Here is the break point (i am able to add it) however when i start the application and browser run the breakpoint is not being hit

    <style type="text/css">

        body { 
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <img src="~/Content/nancy-logo.png" alt="Nancy logo" /><br />
    This view was rendered using the Nancy Razor view engine
</body>
</html>
```

Picture of the problem:

[image]

The pdb file for the project exists!

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72723/discussion-between-david-ching-and-daniel-eugen).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a controller connected to a view which calls the .cshtml view then it will never get loaded.